# Leave branch as a mere etiquette but with out being able to access it in GIT

Tags: git, git-branch, git-log

I want to be able to virtually delete a branch, so no one can checkout it and make changes from that point, but leaving the name of the branch as an indicator or etiquette in the history.

In other words I want gitk to keep showing me the names of my past branches, whether or not I had deleted them.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sounds like you want [tagging](http://git-scm.com/book/en/Git-Basics-Tagging).

Example usage:

`git tag archive/branch_name`

`git push origin archive/branch_name`

You could then delete the branch referenced by the tag.

Personally, I use the below [alias](https://git.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/Aliases) to tag a branch, push it and delete both the remote branch and the local one:

```
tagarchive = !f() { git tag archive/$1 origin/$1 && git push origin :$1 && git push origin archive/$1 && git branch -d $1; }; f
```

Usage: `git tagarchive branch_name`

Comment: Thanks, that did it. But I'm having a problem with the alias you passed, it's thowing 'f() { git tag archive/$1 origin/$1 && git push origin :$1 && git push origin archive/$1 && git branch -d $1: 1: f() { git tag archive/$1 origin/$1 && git push origin :$1 && git push origin archive/$1 && git branch -d $1: Syntax error: end of file unexpected (expecting "}")' when executed.

Besides, is it posible to delete the branch you are currently on? because to tag the branch you have to be on that branch, or it isn't necesary?

Comment: I copied that straight from my git config - perhaps you miscopied? It does look like you're missing the closing bracket, judging by the error message. You're right about the branch deletion - I believe you would have to be on a different branch first.

Comment: changin to : 'tagarchive =  !git tag archive/$1 origin/$1 && git push origin :$1 && git push origin archive/$1 && git branch -d $1' made it. Thanks!